# ARCore Object Rotation Based On Where I First Open The Apps

Tags: android, rotation, arcore, quaternions

Project: I made an ARCore apps. Basically you place 2 points (Andy a.k.a The Android Robot) then it will spawn object (cupboard) in the middle of these 2 points.

Problem: Basically i want the door of my cupboard is facing based on where i place those 2 points. But, it turn out the cupboard's door will face where i am facing when i FIRST open the app.

Tested on emulator, and same problem when on device

On emulator, i do:
I open the app, the camera is pointed towards the couch. then I randomly place the 2 points (doesn't matter where) the spawned AR model cupboard door will face the couch.
I navigate the app to face the window, close it, open it again while keeping it facing the window. Then I randomly place the 2 points again (doesn't matter) AND NOW the spawned cupboard door will face the window. At this point no matter where i go/face/rotate on emulator, the cupboard door will face the window.

Any idea how to rotate the object based on where I place the points?

Related code:

```
    //Slope
    float m_slope = (pose0.tz() - pose1.tz()) / (pose0.tx() - pose1.tx());
    float perpedicular_slope = -1f/m_slope;

    float middle_z = (pose0.tz() + pose1.tz())/2;
    float middle_x = (pose0.tx() + pose1.tx())/2;

    float b = middle_z - middle_x * perpedicular_slope;


    // backward/forward from middle
    float DEVIATION_X = 0f; // TODO: change this >0 to make it on side
    float new_x = middle_x + DEVIATION_X * side;
    float new_y = perpedicular_slope*new_x+b;

    float[] pos0_2 = { new_x , (pose0.ty() + pose1.ty())/2, new_y};
    float[] rotation0_2 = {0,0,0,1};

    /* BASICALLY Above is the code to positioning the cupboard Beside the middle of 2 points */

    Anchor anchor0_2 =  session.createAnchor(new Pose(pos0_2, rotation0_2));
    AnchorNode anchorNode0_2 = new AnchorNode(anchor0_2);
    anchorNode0_2.setParent(arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene());

    TransformableNode andy0_2 = new TransformableNode(arFragment.getTransformationSystem());
    andy0_2.setParent(anchorNode0_2);
    andy0_2.setRenderable(cupBoardRenderable);

    andy0_2.select();
    andy0_2.setWorldRotation(Quaternion.axisAngle(new Vector3(0, 1f, 0), 0f));

    //Already try something like this too, but pose0.qy() return very little number like 0.01-1 so i mult 100
    //andy0_2.setWorldRotation(Quaternion.axisAngle(new Vector3(0, 1f, 0), pose0.qy()*100f));
```

[Facing the couch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s96Z7.jpg)

[Facing the windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfPZ2.jpg)

[Cupboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebSJc.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the transform.LookAt() function.  By supplying the transform you want your asset to look at Unity will take care of the rotation for you.

Comment: Sorry, i am developing on Android Studio. There is function setLookDirection() which I try but it is similar to setWorldRotation and setLocalRotation